# Comma separation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a set of productids like (123565,589655,45585,666669,5888) I want to put comma in front and back of these set of ids Like(,123565,589655,45585,666669,5888,)..

How can i write  the XSLT code for doing this?

Comment: Could you show a sample of your XML, and your expected output too? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$yourSequence" 
                                    separator=","/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
```

Comment: That's cool, I didn't even know about the `@separator` attribute; live and learn… +1

Answer (score 0):

Depends terribly on your input XML file and what you want the output to look like. In any case, since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use the `string-join()` function.

Let's say you have an input XML file that looks like this:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Product #1</name>
    <id>123565</id>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product #1</name>
    <id>589655</id>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product #1</name>
    <id>45585</id>
  </product>
</products>
```

You could have a stylesheet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="SEPARATOR" select="','"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--
    Join the values of each products/product/id element with $SEPARATOR; prepend
    and append the resulting string with commas.
    -->
    <xsl:value-of
      select="concat($SEPARATOR, string-join((products/product/id),
        $SEPARATOR), $SEPARATOR)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which would produce the following output:

```
,123565,589655,45585,
```

If you edit your question to include your input XML and what you want your output XML to look like, I can modify my answer accordingly.